# I want the div out of my td as seen in the picture

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this HTML Code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p id="price">10000</p>
            <div class="no" hidden="hidden">Description</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And my jquery code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#price").live("mouseenter", function () {
            $(this).next("div.no").show();
        });
        $("#price").live("mouseleave", function () {
            $(this).next("div.no").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now I want the  tag in a specific height.
Let me describe you in picture:

Before entering the mouse the table is like this:
[image]

After entering the mouse the above code would make this:
[image]

But the thing I want to have something like following:
[image]
How can I do this?

Comment: You need to use absolute positioning.

Comment: What is your current CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could help you:

I used hover instead of live, since you're recreating an "onElementEventMouse", check it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9bbz5/

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p id="price">10000</p>
            <div class="no" hidden="hidden">Description</div>
        </td>
         <td>
            <p id="price">10000</p>
        </td>
         <td>
            <p id="price">10000</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#price {
    background-color: yellow;
    height:40px;
    width: 200px;
}
td {
    text-align: center;
}
.no {    
    background-color: red;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p#price").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).next("div.no").show();
      },
      function () {
        $(this).next("div.no").hide();
      });
  });
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Give it an absolute position using css, and add a z-index if for some reason the div goes behind the td.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the original DIV hidden, make a clone of it, and position it absolutely in the document relative to the TD you have hovered over.

Something like:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var cloned_div;
        $("#price").live("mouseenter", function () {
            cloned_div = $(this).next("div.no").clone();
            // determine position of the hovered TD
            // position cloned DIV based on that
            // show cloned div
        });
        $("#price").live("mouseleave", function () {
            // destroy / remove cloned div
        });
    });
```

jQuery docs on clone: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to be solved by CSS. You can set the div.no to a negative top margins so it overlaps the p#price

Answer (score 0):

Lets take into consideration the css (just for temporary purpose)

```
.no{
    display:none;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    background-color:YELLOW;
}
#price{
    background-color: RED;
}
```

the javascript code is as follows:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter","#price", function (e) {
    $(this).next("div.no").show().css({
        position: "absolute",
        marginLeft:e.clientX + "px",
        marginTop: e.clientY + "px"
    });
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", "#price",function () {
    $(this).next("div.no").hide();
});
```

Try this code i am sure it helps with what you get.
I have added the jsfiddle link as well for your testing as below:
http://jsfiddle.net/CeYkx/1/